# Locking keys like ctrl or alt in emacs

Tags: emacs

When reading through the code at times, its a pain to keep pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key or <kbd>alt</kbd> key in addition to <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>p</kbd> or other combination to keep moving around in the code. 
I was wondering if there is a way to lock these keys for a while and then be able to just use combination keys to navigate around

NOTE : I don't want answers like `use vim`. I don't have time to read stupid answers please.

Comment: You *might* be interested in one of the vim-like packages for Emacs, however. e.g.: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could for example define a minor mode for which the keymap assigns navigation commands to just letters, without the `C-` or `M-` modifier.

For example:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode my-minor-mode
  "Navigate with easy key bindings"

  ; Make this a global mode (i.e. active in all buffers)
  :global t

  ; "foo" will be printed in the modeline when this mode is active
  :lighter " foo"

  ; Setup the keymap
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (define-key map (kbd "n") 'next-line)
            map))
```

Then, you can assign this mode to a key binding to easily switch it on and off:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'my-minor-mode)
```

---

You might want to look at the documentation to better understand how `define-minor-mode` works:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`define-minor-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: yeah that sounds fine. Thanks ! I'll get started!

Comment: what do `global` and `lighter` help with ?

Comment: I edited the answer to add comments about `:global` and `:lighter`

Answer (score 2):

Try `M-x view-mode`. That binds lots of single characters to various navigation commands.  Type `C-h f view-mode` to see the entire list.